Structure of a quantity which is conserved under collision processes
In a book about statistical physics it is stated, that for each quantity which is conserved under elastic collisions,
$$\Psi(\vec v_1)+\Psi(\vec v_2)= \Psi(\vec v_1') + \Psi(\vec v_2')$$ there is only the possibility
$$\Psi(\vec v) = A + \vec B \vec v + C \vec v^2$$
with constants $A$, $\vec B$, $C$.
Why is this so? Considering conservation of energy and momentum this structure satisfies the first equation. But why are there nor other possibilities possible? This is the point where I'm not able to follow. My book just states (translated from German)

If there were further independent invariants, so one could not allow
all solutions of the three conservation laws for the collision; There
were additional restrictions on the collision process, contrary to the
assumption only these conservation laws define the collision.

however I wonder how to derive this from any first physical/mathematical principles. Why is it just clear?

Which book? Author, title, page...

wouldn't give sense to answer this, because the book is quite old.

By definition, elastic collisions are processes that conserve linear momentum and energy, nothing else. In general, there is no other independent conserved quantity, which should be derived from those two. This means that $\Psi = f(\vec{p}, E)$. Moreover, being additive on a system of particles, it must be linear both in $\vec{p}$ and $E$, i.e. $\Psi = a + \vec{b}\vec{v} + cE$. Thus, it must be at most of the second order in $\vec{v}$ (from the energy contribution).
A case could be made about the possible dependence from angular momentum, but in the collision of two particles can be neglected choosing the appropriate pole.
